# Ruby use find to loop through an array and return the matching value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to loop through an array using find to find and return a specific id.
This is my structure:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "emp_id": "1",
      "tutorials": [
        {
          "id": "test1"
        },
        {
          "id": "test2"
        },
        {
          "id": "test3"
        },
        {
          "id": "test4"
        },
        {
          "id": "test5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
 }
```

So basically I am trying to see if the above structure contains a tutorial id of 'test3' and return it.(i.e return 'test3' in this case)

I can get the desired result using a combination of map and find like this:

```
 my_tutorial = employees.map { |employee|
  employee.tutorials.find { |tutorial|
    tutorial.id == 'test3'
  }
}.first

my_tutorial
```

But I want to know if there is a better way using find . I tried the following but it returns the ruby object instead of the id.

```
 employees.find { |employee|
  employee.tutorials.find { |tutorial|
    tutorial.id == 'test3'

  }
}
```

Comment: where did that structure came from? It does not seem valid. Inside `tutorials` you have a hash with multiple values for the key `id`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't want to print the whole structure here. So i modified the hash and made a mistake. I fixed it now

Comment: If you want something inside the object returned then get it-the behavior you're seeing is how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did to make it work using find. Not sure if it is any better:

```
my_id = employees.find { |employee|
  employee.tutorials.find { |tutorial|
    tutorial.id == 'test3'

  }
}
my_id.tutorials.first.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to get only the first record do as follows:

```
employees[0].tutorials.detect {|r| r.id == 'test3' }
```